# How to draw a tree from a Prufer sequence?

Tags: graph-theory, trees

What's the process of drawing a tree from a prufer sequence?

I understand that there are 2 more vertices than the no. of no.'s from the sequence. I also understand that you join the number that isn't in the sequence... What do you do when you've used all the numbers in the Prufer sequence and you're left with 2 numbers?

Answer (score 1):

See here: [Labeled tree from Prüfer sequence](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Labeled_Tree_from_Pr%C3%BCfer_Sequence)

Especially step 3

Comment: I'm looking at the explanations but I still don't understand how to the process is done. Could you explain?